# Save pdf from excel vba while preserving external links

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba which saves two sheets from excel to pdf with the following script

```
Sub Create_PDF()
Dim choice As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim fileSavePath As String          ' Prompt the user for their choice
Worksheets("sheet1").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
directory, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
End Sub
```

All these sheets I am saving are with specific layout and textboxes with external hyperlinks. On windows the links are working in the saved PDF unlike on MacOS. I had idea to convert excel to word and then to pdf, but the function which converts excel to word is also not working on MacOS. Is there any way at all to preserve the hyperlinks?

Comment: It would be useful to have samples of the hyperlinks, are they pointing at: web, share$, local drive?

Comment: @5202456 to web